# DOM Selector for the content that is added by the ::after modifier

Tags: javascript, html, dom, queryselector

I'm looking for a DOM selector (read css or javascript selector) that allows me to get the text that is inserted by an element's `::after` modifier.

minimum code example:

```css
p.something::after {
  content: "content is now readable";
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class='something'></p>
<p>
  Something else
</p>
```

So to rephrase the question, how can I get the content of the first paragraph (`content is now readable`) using javascript/css selectors.

I would like to exclude any libraries as they may not be available and am looking for a vanilla JS or CSS answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `getComputedStyle` together with it's second argument:

```
function readAfterPseudo(el) {
  var cs = getComputedStyle(el, '::after');
  console.log(cs.content);
}

readAfterPseudo(document.querySelector('.something'))
```

More information can be found at MDN: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Can not edit the property, is a read only object.